# Different floating point delimeter on servers

Tags: php, apache, configuration, floating-point

I have a windows pc with xampp installation where i develop my application. Floats will be displayed like 1.234. Iam from germany and i think it would be better to display them like 1,234.

When i finished a part of this application i push the code on my server. The server is linux with a simple apache server. On my server floats are displayed like 1,234.

I do some calculation on a page. On my localhost this works very fine but online there are completely different values.

Is there a php.ini option i have to set or am i missing something else?

Thanks

EDIT:
The Locale is set on both machines to 'de_DE'.

Comment: Isn't this just about locales? http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php. If it turns out that you can alter it by playing with this `setlocale()`... then you might want to set the locale of your apache the way you want it to be.

Comment: what about your database? Are the floats correctly stored?

Comment: Ok. Thanks for helping. Found the problem. Under my localhost (windows) i have to set the locale as german and not something like 'de_DE'.